# iOS Metal: profiling kernels shows wrong times

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, metal, compute-shader

I use one `ComputeCommandEncoder` to dispatch 4 different Metal kernels and I want to know how much time does it take to execute each kernel.

When I profile the app with Xcode's *Capture GPU Frame* tool, Xcode claims that the overall time spent by executing the 4 kernels is `100µs`. The problem is that *every single time* I profile the app, the reported overall execution time is *exactly* `100µs`.

Out of curiosity, I tried to execute and profile only one kernel out of the 4. To my surprise, the Xcode profiler showed again exactly `100µs` as the overall computation time. (Take a look at the illustrations below.)

**How do I determine the actual execution times of individual kernels?**

[image: Profiling of all 4 kernels.] vs.
[image: Profiling just one kernel.]

Comment: After upgrading to `iOS 10 beta 7` and `Xcode 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h)` from `iOS 9.3.5` and `Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)`, the problem is gone and GPU Frame Capture shows real kernel execution durations!